# How to test code that returns external information

Tags: c++, testing

Let's say I want to make a module of code that provides utilities for fetching information about the user's monitors. Just looking at perhaps one function, let's say we want to write a getPrimaryMonitorSize(), which will return the horizontal and vertical pixel count of the primary monitor of the system.

I'm relatively new to TDD and I have no clue how to appropriately test this type of function. As far as I can see I have two options, both I'm uncomfortable with:

1. hard code the values for the system I'm currently developing on.
2. basically do exactly what my implementation is going to be doing and fetching the values through OS API calls.

The first creates a system dependency: bad.
The second seems silly, since I know my implementation is going to be doing the exact same thing to fetch the values and then deliver them to the function caller. Also just the incredible bloat it would create to effectively have the same code in my test code that is in my production code.

I'm assuming my relative inexperience and lack of familiarity with test code is creating this issue for me, but I can't see an obvious solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one way to test it.

You are thinking "test that it does return the monitor data properly".  To test that you need a hardware farm and to deploy your code over it, with known good results on each piece of hardware, and validate it.

There is also "test that it can be used".  Some other code is going to ask this question and expect it to be useful.  Here, we mock the system and allow other code to get a variety of responses from it, and test that the connection and interaction gices valid results.

Our test harness here is code that interacts with the display.  It asks for resolution information, then displays things in that display.  The mock is not just the "what is the resolution" but also the path to show pixels (or maybe read pixels).

We can use this to teat our API design: the business logic interacts with what it thinks is a real display, and if sufficient we have a good API.

Then we slide in our version.

Another form of testing is getting into the guts.  We can mock lower level APIs we are using - the OS specific stuff - and our OS agnostic API talk to it.  Once we write up the OS soecific mock, we can record the responses on a pile of real hardware and have our mock play them back even on a system withimout that hardware.  We now have a non-system dependent test suite (OS specific) for our API.

We write a suite like this for each OS/platform, and we can test our system's internals.

However, if we are single platform and we are just repeating mindlessly an OS API, maybe we shouldn't exist.  If the conversion is valuable, then the conversion code can be tested: but the OS testing is out of scope.

The OS specific Mocks are untested here: so make them as noop as they can be.  Identical signatures etc, just with an extra this pointer that lets you swap out the implementation.  The real version blindly calls the OS API: the mock fakes it.

Here we have to validate visually, as we don't have the ability to replace the OS for testing, or test with real hardware.

Comment: So if i wanted to test that the way i was calling the api functions was correct and the data interpreted from them was correct i would have to create fake api functions which return the same data regardless of system and have the specified behaviour of the api functions?

Comment: @wigi426 I'd have a suite of different implementations of the OS api functions, based off of what real  hardware returns.  Then (assuming your API is a non-trivial transformation) you can test the transformation of those values.

Answer (score 1):

### Heading ##To create (unit) testable code it is good to learn about interfaces (abstract basec classes) and dependeny injection.

For your case you want control during testing, e.g. fixed values of monitor resolution and or even testing with different resolutions independent of your own monitor. And in production you want to ask the OS for the actual resolution.

Thus you should declare an interface for getting monitor resoltion first. You can then make as many implementations of this interface as you want and use them in your production code and/or test code.

Here is an example of that :

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

//getPrimaryMonitorSize

struct rect_2d_t
{
    std::size_t widht;
    std::size_t height;
};

// create an abstract baseclass/interface
// representing what you want to do
class monitor_info_itf
{
public:
    virtual ~monitor_info_itf() = default;
    virtual rect_2d_t getPrimaryMonitorSize() const noexcept = 0;
};


// Implementation for real code
class monitor_info_t :
    public monitor_info_itf
{
public:
    rect_2d_t getPrimaryMonitorSize() const noexcept override
    {

        rect_2d_t retval;

        // some API call to get primary monitor size here
        // ::GetPrimaryMonitorSizeFromOS(&retval.x,&retval.y); 

        return retval;
    }
};

// Implementation for unit test
class monitor_info_stub_t :
    public monitor_info_itf
{
public:
    explicit monitor_info_stub_t(const rect_2d_t& size) :
        m_size{size}
        {
        }

    rect_2d_t getPrimaryMonitorSize() const noexcept override
    {
        return m_size;
    }

private:
    rect_2d_t m_size;
};

// class to test that is using monitor info
// the class itsef will never call the OS API function directly
// but the method on the interface we created earlier
// For this we are going to use depedency injection

class renderer_t
{
public:
    renderer_t(const monitor_info_itf& monitor_itf) :
        m_monitor_itf{monitor_itf}
    {
    }

    void render()
    {
        // create bitmap or something using monitor information
        auto rect = m_monitor_itf.getPrimaryMonitorSize();
    }

private:
    const monitor_info_itf& m_monitor_itf;
};


// production code 
int main()
{
    monitor_info_t monitor_info;
    renderer_t renderer{monitor_info}; // inject the "real" implementation
    renderer.render(); //uses the resolution from the real system
}

// test code
void unit_test()
{
    monitor_info_stub_t monitor_info_stub{{3440,1920}};
    renderer_t renderer{monitor_info_stub}; // inject the "test" implementation
    renderer.render(); //uses the resolution from the mock
}
```

Comment: doesn't this code still create a system dependency for the unit test? you've hard coded the resolution. So the test will erroneously fail on other development environments

Comment: No in your unit test you should not link with the `monitor_info_itf`. The whole idea is to put the "interface" in a seperate header file. The implementations of the implementation go into different source files. The stub you link with your test executable and the production code should link with your final executable.

Comment: The "hard coded" resolution is for one test say "test case 1" in another test case you can create a test with an instance with a different resolution. That's the beauty of stub classes you can control them for you tests (unlike the monitor resolutions of real systems)

Comment: But then im only testing the interface, sometimes OS calls can be pretty involved, with this method i wouldn't be able to test that the calls to OS functions and interpretation of the received data are  performing as expected

Comment: Well kind of you can still make seperate tests for the classes that do call the OS. But somehow you need to find a way that your interfaces return the correct values for the machine the tests run on. E.g. like dxdiag make a test app that stores the values you get through the interfaces to a file and compare them to system information. Unit tests cannot test everything, but the can test a lot of your building blocks :)